# Adding a new row in a dataframe

Tags: r

Given a dataframe

```
category <- c("A", "B", "C")
r1 <- c(2, 2, 2)
r2 <- c(3, 3, 3)
r3 <- c(1, 1, 1)
r4 <- c(4, 4, 4)
df <- data.frame(category, r1, r2, r3, r4)
```

How do I calculate and add a new row `D` by multiplying values in `A` and `B` per column and dividing by the sum of `C`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to add a new row? Or do you mean a new column? Because values that belong together should be in the same row not in the same column.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can do

```
 df$r5 <- (df$r2 * df$r4)/sum(df$r4)
```